# Create a dataframe column to tag sections of a dataframe between keywords

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a fast pandas way of labeling sections within a dataframe.

Suppose I have a dataframe column A with some strings in it, I'd like to create a new column B that tags the sections incrementally between the keyword 'hi' like so:

```
A   B
hi  
a   1
b   1
hi
d   2
f   2
g   2
hi
```

Comment: Maybe it's better if you post your real problem, How we know the difference between the words and the tags, also what do you mean with tag the sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.assign(C = df['A'].eq('hi').cumsum().mask(df['B'].isna()))
Out: 
    A    B    C
0  hi  NaN  NaN
1   a  1.0  1.0
2   b  1.0  1.0
3  hi  NaN  NaN
4   d  2.0  2.0
5   f  2.0  2.0
6   g  2.0  2.0
7  hi  NaN  NaN
```